# PHP calculation returns NAN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform some calculation on Data retrieved from database , 
but evertime I run this code I get  **NAN** as output.

```
function calculateNPS()
    { 
        $queryTotal = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM message";
        $resullTotal = mysqli_query($link ,$queryTotal);

        $queryYes= "SELECT count(visit) as  yes FROM message WHERE visit='Yes'";
        $resultYes = mysqli_query($link ,$queryYes);

         $queryNo = "SELECT *count(visit) as no FROM message WHERE visit='No'";
        $resultNo = mysqli_query($link ,$queryNo);

        $yescount = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTotal);
        $nocount=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNo);
        $totalcount=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultYes);

        $nps = ((float)($yescount['yes'])/(float)($totalcount['total'])*100)-((float)($nocount['no'])/(float)($totalcount['total'])*100);
        echo $nps;

}
```

Comment: `SELECT *count(visit)` is invalid. You'll want to echo/log the results for each to make sure they contain what you think.

Comment: @aynber corrected that a while ago, but still no change in output.

Comment: `NaN` sounds like it's coming from Javascript, not PHP. As I mentioned, you'll need to double-check the values of each variable by logging them or using echo/var_dump to see what they contain so you can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @aynber PHP can display NAN when necessary. it even has a NAN keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I hope thats just a test-script, because there are a lot of issues you could fall into ;-)

but your problem: i guess its just a typing-mistake. you name the result-var "resullTotal", below you are requesting another var called "resultTotal" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some numeric operations can result in a value represented by the constant NAN. This result represents an undefined or unrepresentable value in floating-point calculations. So it seems you have some problems with the values in the $nps calculation.

I would suggest that you try outputting/inspecting all the params, like `$yescount` or `$yescount['yes']` to make sure you have valid data to start with. Then break your expression into shorter operations until you find the issue.

For instance, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

Also, in your queries you use `$link` but I can't see where it's coming from.